# Matlab - Using findpeaks with fvtool

Tags: matlab, filters

Is there any way I could utilise `findpeaks` in conjunction with `fvtool`? I would like to know where on the frequency axis the maximum and minimum of my frequency response happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fvtool` is interactive so it doesn't let you recover an data in a script. Fortunately you can use the `freqz` function to get the same frequency response. Something like this might work:

```
[h,w] = freqz(b,a);  % h is frequency response, w normalized frequency
mag = 20*log10(abs(h));
[minval,minidx] = min(mag);
minfreq = w(minidx); 
[maxval,maxidx] = max(mag);
maxfreq = w(mcxidx);
```